# Blade Recursive, increase the depth for padding

Tags: php, laravel-blade

I want to increase the depth `int` each time children are in a item so I can pad out the `a` tag.

Below is my code and I assumed this would work, however the number stays at 1 even though I have got children within my one of the items within `$items`.

`sidebar.blade.php`

```html
<nav class="flex flex-col mt-10">
    <ul class="pl-4">
        @foreach($items as $item)
        <x-layouts.sidebar.items :item="$item"></x-layouts.sidebar.items>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</nav>
```

`sidebar.items.blade.php`

```html
<li>
    @if(count($item) > 0)
        <a href="{{ $item['href'] }}" class="focus:text-blue-500 dark-focus:text-blue-400 focus:outline-none w-full transition duration-500 ease-in-out pl-4 py-2 text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 hover:bg-blue-200 dark-hover:bg-blue-500 transition duration-500 ease-in-out block">
            {{ $item['text'] }} {{ $depth }}
        </a>
        @if (count($item['children']) > 0)
            <ul class="pl-4">
                @foreach($item['children'] as $child)
                    <x-layouts.sidebar.items :item="$child" :depth="$loop->parent->index"></x-layouts.sidebar.items>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        @endif
    @else
        <hr>
    @endif
</li>
```

`Sidebar\Items.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\View\Components\Layouts\Sidebar;

use Illuminate\View\Component;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class Items extends Component
{

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public $item;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    public $depth;

    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @param array $item
     * @param int   $depth
     */
    public function __construct($item = [], $depth = 1)
    {
        $this->item = $item;
        $this->depth += $depth;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return View|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.layouts.sidebar.items');
    }
}
```

Data:

```php
$this->items = [
    [ 'href' => '/home', 'text' => 'Home', 'children' => [], 'active' => 'border-l-2 border-blue-500' ],
    [ 'href' => 'javascript:void(0)', 'text' => 'Test', 'children' => [], 'active' => '' ],
    [ 'href' => 'javascript:void(0)', 'text' => 'Websites', 'children' => [], 'active' => '' ],
    [ 'href' => 'javascript:void(0)', 'text' => 'Websites', 'children' => [], 'active' => '' ],
    [],
    [
        'href' => '/administration',
        'text' => 'Administration',
        'children' => [
            [
                'href' => 'javascript:void(0)',
                'text' => 'Locked Devsites',
                'active' => '',
                'children' => []
            ]
        ],
        'active' => ''
    ],
    [ 'href' => 'javascript:void(0)', 'text' => 'Documentation', 'children' => [], 'active' => '' ],
    [ 'href' => 'javascript:void(0)', 'text' => 'Logout', 'children' => [], 'active' => '' ]
];
```

Result:

```
Home 1
Test 1
Websites 1
Websites 1
Administration 1
Locked Devsites 5
Documentation 1
Logout 1
```

Comment: Can you add an example of what `$items` looks like that is passed into `sidebar.blade.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right what you want to achieve, you don't even need the `$depth` property, since the blade's `@foreach` directive has its own depth property which tells you how nested you are.

In your code, instead using:

```
:depth="$depth"
```

use:

```
:depth="$loop->depth"
```

Comment: This seems closer, updated my question with the data and the change and also added the result. The child is outputting `5`, this should be `2`.

Comment: I just updated my solution, check it out it will work just fine now.